# password error...?

Tags: mysql, authentication, passwords, case

I've a MySQL table for my program's login informations. password datatype is varchar. When I try to login to my password, it doesn't care that my charactors whether lower case or upper case. if I enter the correct letters, it logs me in. What is the solution for this? Much appreciated your help

Comment: Be more elaborate. Your question is vague !

Comment: Don't store your passwords as plain text

Answer (score 1):

This happens because by default mysql is [case insensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html):

```
mysql> create table foo (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, bar VARCHAR(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> insert into foo values ('','Hello'),('','hello');
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.03 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from foo where bar = 'hello';
+----+-------+
| id | bar   |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Hello |
|  2 | hello |
+----+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The easiest option - by far - is to not store your passwords in plain text! Encrypt or hash them and store the hashed/encrypted value instead.

---

A simple way to store a hash for a password is to use the built-in `md5` function:

```
mysql> SELECT MD5('secret');
+----------------------------------+
| MD5('secret')                    |
+----------------------------------+
| 5ebe2294ecd0e0f08eab7690d2a6ee69 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.40 sec)
```

Then, your query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `sometable` WHERE `the_password` = MD5('secret');
```

Note, this is a one-way hash - that is, you cannot practically get the word `secret` from the hashed version. So you cannot use this to display passwords in a user registration welcome email, for example.

MySQL supports a few [encryption and hashing functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) which you should review.

Comment: First of all,  Thank you for your answer.I'm new to Java and MySQL.can you post how to encrypt or hash them and store ? :)